# Xamarin support for IOS carekit

Tags: ios, xamarin, carekit

Does xamarin has apis to work with the IOS carekit ?
https://github.com/carekit-apple/CareKit

Comment: Create a binding library for it: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/